# How to prevent logged SSH users to view /var/www/html/ (Apache2) directory?

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

I would like to use permissions, to prevent 5-10 users to view the HTML webserver. In order words, how to prevent logged SSH users to view /var/www/html/ (Apache2) directory?

I thought about creating a group (restrictedgroup) and to add the given users to this group. (no idea really how).

Once done, then, to go to /var/www/html/ and to do something, if possible, to restrict the directory from browsing.

My OS is Debian.

Answer (score 1):

> In order words, how to prevent logged SSH users to view /var/www/html/
>   (Apache2) directory?

Your `/var/www/html/` should be set to specific user and group ownership (either `www-data` or `apache2`) by using `chown` tool, if it is not set already (it should be, though).

Then apply `750` permission to `/var/www/html`, by executing `chmod 750 /var/www/html`. This kind of permission gives rights to apache user and members of apache group and restricts anyone else from browsing the directory. Be careful, as there may be other system users that may require access to contents of this directory.

Now, here comes the hard part. If your 5-10 system users are **sudoers** (able to execute root command via sudo) then, to my best knowledge, there isn't much that can be done.